# Can I run a natural gas dryer from a portable propane tank?

Tags: dryer, gas

I bought a modular home in the woods with no w/d hookup,I want to know if it's safe & OK to hookup a 5 gallon propane tank to a gas dryer, plug it in & dry my clothes?

Do I have to change something in the dryer to run propane from natural gas?
Just trying to be safe. I don't want to blow me & my house up!  ANY HELP OUT THERE PLEASE WOULD APPRECIATED!

Comment: If you post the brand, model, and serial number (usually found on the rear of the unit or on a plate inside the door of the unit) someone might be able to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: I do believe propane and natural gas require different fittings/settings to work. And, this does sound like a great way to distribute small pieces of your new home across the local environs. Be careful.

Answer (score 5):

If your dryer is set up for natural gas, then it isn't going to run on propane - you'll need to install a propane conversion kit.  Most manufacturers sell these for specific models, and I'm sure there are some generic after-market kits out there too. These generally aren't that difficult to install - you'll basically be changing the limit in the pressure regulator and the size of the orifice to the burner.

Comment: I think I converted mine for $8...though if you count the 2 hours of labor to dismantle the entire dryer (why they just didn't make a simple access panel is beyond me...)

Comment: because an access panel would allow you fix it and if you fix it you will not be buying a new one. welcome to capitalistic consumptionism dressed up as democracy. our economic growth is dependent on continued consumption.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look in the owner's manual to see if the appliance is designed for use with LP gas. Some work with both natural gas and LP gas, some require a special part to convert from natural to LP gas, others are designed specifically for only one or the other.

Answer (score -3):

yes you can.  Propane comes in at a higher pressure than natural gas.  The natural gas orifice will let too much propane through and throw a flame large enough to run up the back of your dryer and possibly out the mesh vent into where your clothes are drying (and frying any sensors along the way).  HOWEVER, you can open up the peep hole so you can watch your ignitor and flame and throttle the block valve on the propane to get a propper flame that will not damage the dryer sensors or set your clothes (or house) on fire.  I know this is an older post, but I thought i'd give my two cents and experience.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Hand-tweaking your dryer to run on propane seems like a pretty dangerous idea.

Comment: I'm with Daniel.  This might be something that could be done as a one off, but for a permanent installation you need to buy the correct regulator.